# How to navigate DVD and BD menus in VLC with keyboard?

Tags: vlc-media-player, dvd, blu-ray

At least with blu-rays I'm experiencing mouse-offset, with some releases I can't select menu elements at all (rendering also may be partially broken). Being able to navigate using keyboard would solve this issue and may be preferred overall as the discs are designed to be controlled by using a remote.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was likely caused by forgetting the 'crop' option (to 4:3) on:

[image: screenshot]